# How can I add some white space beneath the last item in a ListView.builder? so that I can properly tap the last checkbox?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview, dart

[image]

The last item of my `ListView` goes behind the `FloatingActionButton`. How can I make the `ListView` scroll higher up or maybe add an empty `Container` as its last item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `padding` is what you are looking for:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('Label $index'),
            Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: (_) {}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```